# expresion regular solo permita un espacio

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular que sólo admite letras y tildes, sin embargo tengo el problema que me deja ingresar varios espacios entre nombres, ejemplo: Juan -------- Lopez
Mi expresión es la siguiente:

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$
```

investigando sé que la expresion para sólo aceptar un espacio máximo es la siguiente:

```
(\s{0,1})
```

Pero no logro saber como incorporarla a la expresión completa, alguien podria decirme como se une?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba con esta

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+)*$
```

```
    1. [a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]    caracteres
    2. +      repetir uno o mas, los caracteres
    3. 
       (  
          1. \s     un espacio en blanco  
          2. [a-zA-Z0-9À-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]   caracteres
          3. +     repetir uno o mas, los caracteres 
       )  
    4. *       el grupo se puede repetir cero o mas veces
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente¡

Comment: \s admite tab y salto de línea,  https://regex101.com/r/0CZkBS/2 , ademas no se porque agregaste los números.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría algo como esto:

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñÑ]+( [a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñÑ]+)*$
```

test: https://regex101.com/r/C35jxT/2

`\s` admite tabs y saltos de línea, por eso usaría simplemente el espacio en este caso.